MainActivity created and destroyed then created again on first run by Android Studio
when I run a new app the first time MainActivity is created then destroyed and then created again. This happens only on the first launch after installing from Android studio.

MainActivity.kt
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        Log.d("App-Test", "Main Activity Created")
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        Log.d("App-Test", "Main Activity Destroyed")
    }
}

activity_main.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/app_name" />

</LinearLayout>

AndroidManifest.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.DummyApp"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.DummyApp">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>

What I've tried
It works fine on subsequent launches from Android Studio.
Also works fine when installed via adb  :
./gradlew assembleDebug
./gradlew installDebug

What to expect
It should only create MainActivity once when installed

This behavior where MainActivity is created, destroyed and then created again only on the first launch after installing from Android Studio, is likely due to the instant run feature of the Android Studio.
You can verify this by disabling the instant run in Android Studio and then testing the app again.
